# JQuery timer не могу запустить вперед

Tags: jquery

Я написал код, и он где то дает сбой, не могу понять почему, он тупо не выводит числа.Помогите разобраться почему`

```
var _Seconds = $('.timer').text(),
  int;
int = setInterval(function() {
  if (_Seconds > 0) {
    _Seconds++;
    $('.timer').text(_Seconds);
  }
}, 1000);

        <span class = "timer">23 000 000+</span> `
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что `$('.timer').text()` возвращает строку, а строка "23 000 000+" непреобразуема в число.

```js
var _Seconds = +$('.timer').text(),
  int;
int = setInterval(function() {
  if (_Seconds > 0) {
    _Seconds++;
    $('.timer').text(_Seconds.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ") + "+");
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="timer">23000000</span>
```

```js
var _Seconds = +$('.timer').text();
function go() {  
  if (_Seconds > 0) {
    _Seconds++;
    $('.timer').text(_Seconds.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ") + "+");
  }
  var millisec = Math.ceil(Math.random()*10) * 500;
  console.log("time in seconds: ", millisec/1000);
  setTimeout(go, millisec);
}
go();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="timer">23000000</span>
```

Comment: а как сделать что бы таймсет рандомный был? или вот например сначала через секуну а потом через 5

Comment: @ДмитрийЗубков В этом случае надо использовать `setTimeout`. Сейчас.

Comment: Вы просто топ)) Спасибо большое)

Comment: @ДмитрийЗубков На здоровье. Успехов!

Comment: Я верстальщик) Мне это точно пригодиться0)) Я уже кстати в процессе изучения JS и JQ, да и работаю с ними часто, поэтому чем глубже, тем интереснее - вот что я хочу сказать, еще раз спасибо)